# Blender project opens with nothing but basic cube

Tags: blend-files

I was doing a sculpt project.

I tried to open it and after some waiting, there's only a basic cube in my project. Every other object gone. Blender had not crashed last time when I was working on it. Just re-opened my file and everything is gone. I tried recovering last session and recovering autosave, both didn't work. The file still has about 450mb even with basic cube. Is there any chance I can get my project back?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you tell us only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Any chance you hid your object by mistake? Is it listed in the outliner?